# How to group elements in a list in with respect to another list in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, grouping

I have 2 lists

`in1=[1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,5]`

`in2=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k']`

I want to group the second list based on the same elements in the first list i.e.

Output has to be

`out=[['a','b','c'],['d','e'],['f'],['g','h','i'],['j','k']]`

Explanation: the first 3 elements of the first list are the same, so I want the first 3 elements of the 2nd list to be grouped together (and so on)

If anyone can help out, it would be great!

~Thanks

Comment: Based on the first list - Can you explain that a bit more?

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. But the idea is, based on same elements in the first list. i.e. the first 3 elements of the first list are the same. so i want the first 3 elements in the 2nd list to be grouped together and so on

Comment: There is a difference between asking a question and dropping a bunch of requirements. You did the latter.

Comment: I am sorry I didnt mean to. The question is the question of the post and requirements are in the description (this is what I thought while framing mine, a little new here. Sorry if this wasnt expected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `zip` the lists, then `itertools` to the rescue.

```
from itertools import groupby

in1 = [1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,5]
in2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k']    

result = [[c for _, c in g] for _, g in groupby(zip(in1, in2), key=lambda x: x[0])]
print(result)
# [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f'], ['g', 'h', 'i'], ['j', 'k']]
```

---

Non-`itertools` solution:

```
in1 = [1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,5]
in2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k']

result = [[]]
key = in1[0]

for k, v in zip(in1, in2):
    if k != key:
        result.append([])
        key = k
    result[-1].append(v)

print(result)
# [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f'], ['g', 'h', 'i'], ['j', 'k']]
```

Comment: @LukasNeugebauer note that `groupby` will create a new group if an already seen key is encountered again, e.g. you would get the same result with `in1 = [1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,1,1]` as with your `in1`.

Comment: I'm not the person who asked the question, just wanted to show my appreciation for having learned something new. But you meant 'will NOT create a new group', right?

Comment: @LukasNeugebauer no, it WILL create a new group. That's why output would be the same with `in1 = [1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,1,1]`. That's the reason `groupby` is often employed with sorting the input-interable first.