# Locate and consolidate elements in a list that have the same name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list that contains `n` different dataframes each with a unique file name. However, some of these file names are the same but the content in the dataframes differ. What I am looking for is to find the duplicate file names and add columns `A` and `B` together, then consolidate the dataframes into one.

The existing loop I have is:

```
for i in range(len(dfs)):
   file_name = [None] * len(dfs)
   location = [None] * len(dfs)
   match = [None] * len(dfs)
   
   file_name[i] = os.path.split(split_list[i])[1]
   location[i] = re.sub(r'(\d+-\d+-\d+)', '', file_name[i])
   location[i] = location[i].rstrip(' Daily Report.xlsx')

   match[i] = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+', location[i])
```

`match[i]` will contain some duplicate names, and what I am trying to do is locate those duplicate names and for the duplicates, I am looking to add `dfs[i1]['A'] + dfs[i2]['A']`, then consolidate `dfs[i1]` and `dfs[i2]` together (where i1= first of duplicates and i2= second of duplicates). Same for column B, see below.

I have tried adding the following to the loop above but it has issues due to list lengths not matching, nor does it drop the duplicate:

```
def add_dups():
   dfs[i]['A'] = dfs[i]['A'] + dfs[i+1]['A']
   dfs[i]['B'] = dfs[i]['B'] + dfs[i+1]['B']

np.where(match[i] == match[i+1], match[i], add_dups())
```

Any assistance in fixing this code would be much appreciated - thank you!

Edit: Should also mention that `split_list` contains the same number of elements as `dfs`.
Edit2: Column layout for each of the dataframes are the same, just contain different numerical values, i.e. each dataframe contains a column `A`, `B`, and `C`.

Comment: Are these pandas dataframes? If so, please [edit] your question and add the [tag:pandas] tag

Comment: Unrelated: `str.rstrip(' Daily Report.xlsx')` removes all characters in `set(' Daily Report.xlsx')` from the right of your string. E.g., see what `'Hello worlD'.rstrip(' Daily Report.xlsx')` gives you.

Comment: Why do you need to use `np.where` at all? Why not simply group `match` by the same names, and then run `add_dups` for each of the groups?

Comment: @pho Yes, they are pandas dataframes, my apologies. I have added the pandas tag. As for the `rstrip(' Daily Report.xlsx')` that is a common ending to the loaded file names, that part is deliberate and is working as intended to. Instead of `np.where` would you recommend I use `groupby` instead? As by my user name, I am quite new to Python so still plenty that I am learning!

Comment: It will stop working as you intend it to as soon as you encounter a file named e.g. `"verynovice Daily Report.xlsx"`

Comment: Do all of the DataFrames have the same columns? Or just sets of matching DataFrames have the same columns (which may vary across different sets)?

Comment: @ALollz Yes, they have the same columns, just different numerical values within the columns. I have made an edit to the post to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply group `dfs` by the same names in `match`, and then run `add_dups` for each of the groups:

First, let's redefine `add_dups` to take any number of dataframes, and add the specified columns from them all to the first dataframe:

```
def add_dups(cols, *dataframes):
    df0 = dataframes[0]
    for df in dataframes[1:]:
        df0.loc[:, cols] += df.loc[:, cols]

    # You don't really need to return since you added in-place so the original dataframe was modified. 
    # If you don't want to modify the original dataframe, simply do 
    # df0 = dataframes[0].copy() instead on the first line of this function
    return df0
```

Next, let's group all the `dfs` elements by their corresponding `match` elements, and call `add_dups`. You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to collect the dataframes belonging to the same `match` in a list:

```
from collections import defaultdict

unique_dfs = []
unique_match = []

df_groups = defaultdict(list)
for m, df in zip(match, dfs):
    df_groups[m].append(df)

for m, m_dfs in df_groups.items():
    unique_dfs.append(add_dups(['A', 'B'], *m_dfs))
    unique_match.append(m)
```

<sup>Note: you could also use `itertools.groupby` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71378720/843953)</sup>

Now, you should have unique `match` elements in `unique_match`, and their corresponding dataframes with the `'A'` and `'B'` columns added in `unique_dfs`

---

To demonstrate, I wrote the following function which creates dummy dataframes:

```
def make_df(i):
    return pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C']) + i

match = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c']
dfs = [ make_df(i) for i, _ in enumerate(match)]
```

`dfs` now looks like:

```
dfs[0] = 
    A  B  C
 0  1  2  3
 1  4  5  6

dfs[1] = 
    A  B  C
 0  2  3  4
 1  5  6  7

dfs[2] = 
    A  B  C
 0  3  4  5
 1  6  7  8

dfs[3] = 
    A  B  C
 0  4  5  6
 1  7  8  9

dfs[4] = 
    A  B   C
 0  5  6   7
 1  8  9  10
```

If everything works correctly, we expect `dfs[0]` and `dfs[3]` to be added together, `dfs[2]` and `dfs[4]` to be added together, and `dfs[1]` to remain unchanged. The end result should look like:

```
unique_dfs[0] = 
    A   B  C
 0   5   7  3
 1  11  13  6

unique_dfs[1] = 
    A  B  C
 0  2  3  4
 1  5  6  7

unique_dfs[2] =
     A   B  C
 0   8  10  5
 1  14  16  8
```

and that is exactly what we see.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed response. Unfortunately, I am encountering some issues when incorporating this into my script. If I incorporate this into my script, I get an error in the `for m, df in zip(match, dfs):` loop (TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'). I tried replacing `match` with `match[i]` in that loop above which removes the error but then if I put `print(unique_dfs)` at the end of the script it returns `[None]`.

Comment: The line with `zip` shouldn't give you that error. It's more plausible the error comes from `df_groups[m]` in the line after that, which would indicate that `match` is a list of lists (I see now that you've populated `match` with the result of `re.findall`.) Can you edit your question to invite an example of what `match` and `dfs` contains? @verynovice